# A hospital-like place that harvests body parts from people

Tags: story-identification, horror

It seemed like the main character was a female who finds herself in this strange-looking hospital. As she passes by some of the rooms some of the patients are seen nearly lifeless. One man is seen brain dead because they had harvested a part of his brain (they only hint to it with the long scar across his head). Others lie around the hospital or walk crazed throughout the halls. I believe it aired on TV around 2006-2008.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VWGzbk2haeo (Coma - 2012)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xETgGym8cnE (Repo - The Genetic Opera - 2008)?

Comment: http://youtu.be/QBdUv7_hFeE (Pathology - 2008)?